# Conditional substract in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor, tf.keras, subtraction

I'm trying to calculate a custom MSE in tf.keras, such as:

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
```

But I want to calculate the difference `y_true - y_pred`, except when values of `y_true` are equal to `-99.0`.

How could I do this?

Comment: What should it return when `y_true` is `-99.0`?

Comment: Nothing; when `y_true` is `-99.0` I would simply don't want to calculate the `mse` for that sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want the function to return if `y_true == -99.0`?

Can you not do this?

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    #check if the batch of y_true has -99
    if -99 in y_true:
          #do whatever you like with the batch
          return #whatever
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
```

If you meant to average only the errors where y_true is not -99, I guess you can simply do this:

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred)[y_true != -99], axis=-1)
```

Cheers,

Keivan

Comment: Ok, thank you!
PS: when `y_true` is `-99.0` I would simply don't want to calculate the mse for that sample.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.cond(y_true !=  -99.0, lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1),
                                     lambda: #Add logic)
```